# How exclude and remove buttons work?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, product-images

I'd like to know what are the function of the each button, exclude and remove.

I guess that exclude remove from the media folder, Am I right?

[image: Magento media]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exclude -** Hide image from product gallery on the frontend. The image still can be used for Thumbnail (display on cart page) or other 2 options.

**Remove -** Remove image reference from database and delete file from media folder.